# C# Casting generics (covariance and contravariance?)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I need some advice/help on this, I can't see the wood from the trees any more.

It's a straight forward series of classes implementing some interfaces using generics.

Then I'm trying to cast the concrete types for example:

```
MyGenericObject<SomeObject> _obj;

IMyGenericObject<ISomeObject> _genObj = (IMyGenericObject<ISomeObject>)_obj;
```

// Invalid cast

I've read some articles about covariance and contravariance but not too clear why this wouldn't be possible, or how to get round it?

---

So, in this example:

```
public interface IMyObject<in T> where T : IBaseObject
{
    T Activity { get; set; }
}
```

wouldn't work...

---

....because, you can't get and set the Activity property.

In this example, I needed to do:

```
public interface IMyObject<out T> where T : IBaseObject
    {
        T Activity { get; }
    }
```

hope that helps someone, and thanks to all for help!

Comment: Please show the definition of your interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only do that if you declare the interface as having a covariant (`out`) parameter.  You can only do that if the parameter is used covariantly.

For example, if the interface `IMyGenericObject<T>` has a method taking a `T` parameter, this prevents you from declaring the parameter as covariant.  Conversely, if there is a method that returns a `T`, that prevents you from declaring the parameter as contravariant.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment on SLaks's answer, I'm tempted to repeat everything Eric Lippert has ever written on co- and contravariance.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/ and also his answers in SO (most recently https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380213/385844)

To summarize:

You can't cast `IList<string>` to `IList<object>` because it's legal to pass a `FileInfo` to an `IList<object>`, but it is not legal to pass it to an `IList<string>`.

You can't cast an `IList<object>` to an `IList<string>`, because it's legal to retrieve an item from an `IList<string>` and assign it to a string reference, but an `IList<object>` might contain a FileInfo, which can't be assigned to a string reference.

**EDIT 2**

Since you asked for advice, it's also possible to split your interfaces into co- and contravariant parts.  To continue with the list example, you could have these interfaces

```
public interface ICovariantList<out T>
{
    T this[int index] { get; }
    //...
}

public interface IContravariantList<in T>
{
    T this[int index] { set; }
    void Add(T item);
    //...
}

public class SomeList<T> : ICovariantList<T>, IContravariantList<T>
{
    //...
}
```

This allows you to use the class covariantly or contravariantly, depending on the context.

Comment: thanks, i kind of sussed that out although i didn't need the setter in the end anyway... but i know for next time!

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the interface as having a covariant (`out`) generic parameter.

Comment: covariant is `out`; contravariant is `in`.  Mnemonic: "o" for covariant and out; "n" for contravariant and in.

Comment: ok, thanks.  The next problem I have is that the compiler reports: "Error 1 Invalid variance: The type parameter 'xxx must be invariantly valid on 'xxx is covariant."  From what I've read, I need to make the interface read only/invariant.  I have a property of the IMyGenericInterface SomeObject SomeObjectInstance {get;set;} Any ideas?

Comment: @sambomartin: You need to understand how variance works.  A writable variant property is inherently non-type-safe.

Comment: @SLaks - You're right, I do - but I'm learning this through example from someting that initially seemed straightforward. From what phoog is saying - as my interface has a method returning a T, this prevents me declaring the parameter as contravariant (in)?

Comment: @SLaks: A writable **covariant** property is not type safe.  A writable **contravariant** property is exactly what contravariance is all about.

Comment: don't see any reason why this answer should receive those many upvotes